# Recurso With em Java

Tags: java

Oi, a algum tempo descobri que algumas linguagens de programação tem um recurso que se chama `with`.

Por ex: 
 Em JS[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas em Java eu não sei de nada parecido, alguém conhece ??

Comment: Vc quer printar dados em tempo de execução?

Comment: Oi, não, não é isso. Eu postei essa foto junto ali em cima pra demonstrar como ela funciona em Js, só quero saber se alguém conhece algo semelhante em Java.

Comment: Poderia detalhar um pouco mais seu funcionamento?

Comment: Talvez isso seja factível de implementar em java usando magias negras e feitiçaria maligna pesada tais como manipulação de bytecode, processamento de anotações plugado no compilador e acesso direto a memória com `sun.misc.Unsafe`. Nenhuma dessas opções é muito recomendada e todas elas são somente para os grandes mestres Jedis que se converteram ao lado negro da força. Mas de qualquer forma, deve ser possível.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse "recurso" é apenas *syntax sugar* que modifica o escopo de resolução incluindo o objeto passado no `with`.

Embora possa economizar um pouco de digitação, o uso desse recurso pode causar confusão na leitura do código quando há ambiguidades, por isso [ele é desencorajado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Não há um equivalente direto em Java, mas você pode encontrar um equivalente dependendo do seu objetivo.

## Encapsular a chamada ao objeto na própria classe

Por exemplo, vamos pensar num código equivalente:

```
class ClassePrincipal {
    Document document;

    void metodo1() {
        Context context = document.querySelector("body");
        ...
    }
}
```

Se quiser encapsular a chamada sem acessar o objeto `document` diretamente, pode fazer algo assim:

```
class ClassePrincipal {
    Document document;

    void metodo1() {
        Element context = querySelector("body");
        ...
    }

    Element querySelector(String selector) {
        return document.querySelector(selector);
    }
}
```

Embora com um método a mais, nosso método principal agora não precisa mais acessar o atributo.

Bem, para um exemplo tão simples isso parece até ridículo, mas se houver muitas chamadas esse encapsulamento facilita a manutenção do código. Por exemplo:

```
class ClassePrincipal {
    Document document;

    void metodo1() {
        Element context = querySelector("body");
        ...
        Element botao = querySelector("#botao");
        ...
        Element menu = querySelector("#menu");
        ...
        Element tabela = querySelector("table");
        ...
    }

    Element querySelector(String selector) {
        return document.querySelector(selector);
    }
}
```

Esse exemplo é bom principalmente se você por alguma razão quer evitar de lidar diretamente com alguma API, evitando acoplar muito o seu código.

Um caso interessante que já ocorreu comigo foi encapsular o `click` do Selenium porque em algumas circunstâncias ele não encontrava o elemento, então foi possível mudar a implementação para usar uma técnica de clique alternativo.

Claro que isso não funciona se você precisar chamar vários métodos diferentes do objeto em questão, portanto não é um substituto um para um com o `with`, mas pode ajudar nesse cenário específico.

## Import estático

Para chamadas estáticas, que não dependem de uma instância específica de um objeto, o Java oferece ainda o `import static`. Exemplo:

```
class BibliotecaMatematica {
    public static BigDecimal calcularJurosComposto(BigDecimal valorPresente, BigDecimal taxaDeJuros, int periodos) {
        ...
    }
    public static BigDecimal calcularJurosSimples(BigDecimal valorPresente, BigDecimal taxaDeJuros, int periodos) {
        ...
    }
}
```

O modo de uso normal seria:

```
class Calculadora {
    void calcular() {
        BigDecimal v1 = BibliotecaMatematica.calcularJurosComposto(...);
        BigDecimal v2 = BibliotecaMatematica.calcularJurosSimples(...);
    }
}
```

Mas poderíamos criar atalhos assim:

```
import static BibliotecaMatematica.*;

class Calculadora {
    void calcular() {
        BigDecimal v1 = calcularJurosComposto(...);
        BigDecimal v2 = calcularJurosSimples(...);
    }
}
```

É como se os métodos estáticos da primeira classe passassem a fazer parte da segunda classe.

## Inicialização de objetos

Em Visual Basic ou Delphi eu já vi muita gente usar o `with` para inicializar objetos ou estruturas de registro. Por [exemplo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx):

```
With theWindow
    With .InfoLabel
        .Content = "This is a message."
        .Foreground = Brushes.DarkSeaGreen
        .Background = Brushes.LightYellow
    End With

    .Title = "The Form Title"
    .Show()
End With
```

Em Java isso geralmente não é necessário porque damos preferência a padrões como *builder* ou *factory method* ou simplesmente uso de construtores. Exemplo:

```
public class HtmlElement {
    private String tagName;
    private Map<String,String> attributes;
    private HtmlElement(String tagName, Map<String,String> attributes) {
        this.tagName = tagName;
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
    public static HtmlElement of(String tagName, Map<String, String> attributes) {
        return new HtmlElement(tagName, attributes);
    }
}
```

Então o código cliente fica assim:

```
HtmlElement table = HtmlElement.of("table", meusAttributos);
```

## Builder pattern e *fluent interfaces*

Outra alternativa para inicialização é usar o padrão builder com encadeamento de métodos e interfaces fluentes. Não vou colocar a implementação aqui, mas [você pode ver isso em mais detalhes no meu artigo](http://luizricardo.org/2013/08/construindo-objetos-de-forma-inteligente-builder-pattern-e-fluent-interfaces/).

O código para inicializar um objeto ficaria assim:

```
new Pedido()
    .para("José")
    .com(1, "Motocicleta")
    .com(2, "Capacete")
    .fechar();
```

Isso é bem legal para evitar confusão quando há muitos parâmetros.

## Mas e o código *boilerplate*?

Para implementar os padrões acima é necessário muito código. Java é conhecido por precisar de muito código para fazer coisas simples.

Uma alternativa é adotar o projeto [**lombok**](https://projectlombok.org/index.html). Veja o código abaixo:

```
@Data(staticConstructor="of")
public static class Exercise<T> {
    private final String name;
    private final T value;
}
```

A anotação [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) iria gerar todo o código necessário:

```
public static class Exercise<T> {
    private final String name;
    private final T value;

    private Exercise(String name, T value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static <T> Exercise<T> of(String name, T value) {
        return new Exercise<T>(name, value);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Exercise(name=" + this.getName() + ", value=" + this.getValue() + ")";
    }

    protected boolean canEqual(Object other) {
        return other instanceof Exercise;
    }

    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Exercise)) return false;
        Exercise<?> other = (Exercise<?>) o;
        if (!other.canEqual((Object)this)) return false;
        if (this.getName() == null ? other.getValue() != null : !this.getName().equals(other.getName())) return false;
        if (this.getValue() == null ? other.getValue() != null : !this.getValue().equals(other.getValue())) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        final int PRIME = 59;
        int result = 1;
        result = (result*PRIME) + (this.getName() == null ? 43 : this.getName().hashCode());
        result = (result*PRIME) + (this.getValue() == null ? 43 : this.getValue().hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Para um exemplo simples, ele parece até ridículo. Porém para um exemplo mais complicado aonde seja necessário acessar diversos métodos do `Document`, fica super-complicado devido a necessidade de implementar todos estes métodos de delegação na classe externa. Acho que um exemplo de um caso mais real aonde isso facilite ao invés de dificultar se faz necessário.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Meu exemplo é no caso de um método. Se for necessário acessar vários outros há um sério problema de acoplamento. Mas concordo que um exemplo mais real seja melhor. Só que vai ficar para outro dia. :)

Comment: @utluiz **With**  é desencorajado em *javacript*, porém em **Delphi** ele é uma mão na roda já que raramente tem código com *encadeadeamento* o que força a repetir o nome do objeto constantemente. Não programo em VB mas sei que tem o mesmo recurso com a vantagem de usar o *.method*  o que facilita a leitura.
Em Delphi há pelo menos uma desvantagem que é o debugger não exibir o objeto corretamente.

Comment: @MarcosRegis É verdade, mas ao mesmo tempo eu lembro de ver muito código Delphi/VB que usava o `with` para inicializar os atributos de um objeto, o que do ponto de vista de orientação a objetos deveria ser feito em um método *factory* ou um *construtor*. O que acha? Você consegue pensar em algum cenário em que seja interessante o uso do `with`?

Comment: @utluiz Deixando um pouco de lado padrão de projeto (porque vi poucos códigos Delphi usando-os) tem os elementos de DataSources por exemplo. Não sei se conhece Delphi mas quando você cria um DataSource e precisa acessar diversas colunas de um ResultSet voce precisaria usar algo como NomeObjetoConexaoBancoDeDados.NomeObjDataSource_NomeColuna para cada coluna.
Usando o With economiza-se a digitação do objeto a qual se altera o escopo. Parece pouco, mas imagina em um formulário com 20 ou 30 colunas para *setar* os valores... E é aqui que paro. (cont...)

Comment: (cont) ... Tem várias desvantagens como o que mencionei do debugger e até mesmo o autocompletar da IDE, mas quem já está acostumado... No mais, sabendo usar é muito útil e não tem maiores problemas.

Comment: @MarcosRegis Sim, eu conheço Delphi, mas não coloco a mão em código pascal ou object pascal há anos. Realmente este é um caso interessante de uso. Em Java às vezes acontece isso quando se usa JDBC diretamente, mas frameworks como Hibernate geralmente fazem o trabalho de mapear os campos para objetos automaticamente.

Answer (score 2):

No Java 7, foi implementado o ARM(Automatic Resource Management), que permite algo bem similar:

```
try (
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt")
) {
  int c;
  while((c=in.read()) != -1 )
    out.write();
}
```

Veja mais na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Infelizmente, nas versões anteriores, não existe esse recurso.

Comment: O ARM (ou *try-with-resources*) é muito legal, mas acho que não tem muita relação com a sintaxe do `with` que o autor da pergunta quer. O que o ARM faz é automatizar a escrita do conteúdo do bloco `finally` para fechar os recursos abertos, e não permitir acessar os métodos e atributos de algum objeto (que não seja o `this`) sem precisar utilizar o nome de variável correspondente.