# Popular via construtor com hibernate

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, hibernate

Estava lendo este artigo http://blog.caelum.com.br/nao-aprender-oo-getters-e-setters/ e fala sobre usar construtores para popular os objetos e deixar de lado alguns setters. Como posso usar dos construtores para popular um objeto com o hibernate? Na hora de pegar os dados do formulário e salvar por exemplo. É possível?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O artigo citado fala sobre o uso desnecessário de *getters* e *setters*. Esse conceito é correto e o assunto já foi discutido aqui por algumas pessoas, inclusive eu, por exemplo:

- [Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/26037/227)
- [Getters e Setters são obrigatórios ou facilitadores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33723/227)

Entretanto, algo que é uma boa prática em geral não necessariamente funciona em todos os contextos.

Entidades JPA ou Hibernate são um exemplo, pois elas não são entidades imutáveis, pelo contrário, precisam e devem ser mutáveis e expor todos os seus atributos via *getters* e *setters* por definição, além de ter um construtor vazio, caso contrário você receberá um erro.

Claro que você pode ter construtores ou até *builders* para facilitar a criação de objetos, mas isso não remove os requerimentos gerais de entidades JPA.

Um objeto JPA precisa ser mutável porque ele não é um objeto simples, mas é gerenciado pelo 'EntityManager', portanto se você quer alterar algum valor de uma entidade existente você deve ser capaz de recuperar a instância do JPA e alterar os seus valores.

Isso também não significa que você precisa usar esses objetos mutáveis em todo o seu programa. É bem possível usar entidades JPA para fazer a interface com o banco de dados enquanto se expõe esses dados para outras camadas do sistema usando *transfer objects* (TOs ou DTOs), estes imutáveis, sem *setters* e com construtores que forçam o desenvolvedor a informar todos os valores.

Note que o uso de construtores, embora seja interessante, geralmente se torna confuso com entidades que possuem muitos atributos. Uma regra arbitrária diz que mais do que cinco parâmetros em um método faz com que seja difícil de usar. Já vi DTOs com 30 ou 50 parâmetros no construtor e, para piorar, vários construtores. Cada vez que alguém ia dar manutenção nessas classes, por exemplo para adicionar um novo campo, gastava vários minutos tentando decifrar qual parâmetro ia parar em qual atributo, pois a única forma de saber com certeza é contar um a um.

Considere o uso do padrão *builder* para classes com vários atributos. Veja exemplos de como isso pode ser feito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94059/227) e [aqui](http://luizricardo.org/2013/08/construindo-objetos-de-forma-inteligente-builder-pattern-e-fluent-interfaces/).

Resumindo: evite *getters* e *setters* desnecessários, prefira objetos imutáveis, use construtores e *builders*, mas infelizmente, isso não vai funcionar com JPA/Hibernate pois o contexto é diferente.

Comment: Valeu, conseguiu esclarecer bem as minhas dúvidas.